# return records between yesterday and last 7 days + mysql

Tags: mysql

here is the code I am using to return past 24 hours records

```
SELECT  *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  CASE WHEN `created` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

how to return records between yesterday and last 7 days

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with this question

Comment: If this is your usage, you really don't need the `CASE` construct.
In your example you can just use `WHERE created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: This is for cakephp and it's a virtual field. and about the CASE that I am using is for other reason..

Comment: Fair enough, that's why I qualified my comment.. just double checking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `BETWEEN` operator.

```
CASE WHEN created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: Thank you. works like charm. I don't understand some silly people ... give me 7 min to accept the answer. Some people just trying to be silly

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works without case statement, so should be faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE created BETWEEN date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-7) AND date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1);
```

Comment: I need the CASE so if fields are empty to not get error and also not to be shown